# BibLaTeX/Biber sorting names incorrectly

Tags: biber, sorting

I had a sorting complaint that originally began with a hyphenated name, but I've produced a minimal example that's somewhat worse: there are no hyphens and also no sense (ultimately, I need to include the name "Galaz-García" without an error, but this problem seems more fundamental still). The harmless-seeming .bib file here—

```
@article{galazgarciasearle2011,
  title={Cohomogeneity one {Alexandrov} spaces},
  author={Fernando Galaz-Garc{\'i}a and Catherine Searle},
  journal={Transform. Groups},
  volume={16},
  number={1},
  pages={91--107},
  year={2011}
}
@electronic{galazgarciazarei2015,
  title={Cohomogeneity one topological manifolds revisited},
  author={Galaz-Garc{\'i}a, Fernando and Zarei, Masoumeh},
  year={2015},
  howpublished = "\url{http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.09068}",
  eprint = {1503.09068},
  archivePrefix = {arXiv}
}
@article{goertschesmare2014,
  author = "Oliver Goertsches and Mare, Augustin-Liviu",
  journal = "Topology Appl.",
  pages = "36--52",
  publisher = "Elsevier",
  title = "{Equivariant cohomology of cohomogeneity one actions}",
  volume = "167",
  year = "2014"
}
@article{goertschesmare2017,
  title={Equivariant cohomology of cohomogeneity-one actions: The topological case},
  author={Goertsches, Oliver and Mare, Augustin-Liviu},
  journal={Topology Appl.},
  year={2017}
}
@article{grovewilkingziller2008,
  title={Positively curved cohomogeneity one manifolds and 3-{Sasakian} geometry},
  author={K. Grove and B. Wilking and W. Ziller},
  journal={J.~Differential Geom.},
  volume={78},
  pages={33--111},
  year={2008}
}
```

—and the following LaTeX—

```
%% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{disasterbib.bib}
\begin{document}    
\cite{galazgarciasearle2011}
\cite{galazgarciazarei2015}
\cite{goertschesmare2014}
\cite{goertschesmare2017}
\cite{grovewilkingziller2008}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

—produce the following output when compiled with biber, which corresponds to no sorting principles I am familiar with:

[image].

What is going on and what can I fix, generally, to get correct orders?

Comment: The IEEE style is not sorted ...

Comment: It looks sorted by label. I'm not familiar with the ieee style, but I suppose that's what the "alphabetic" in "ieee-alphabetic" stands for.

Comment: @JosephWright, please explain what this means for me. I've tried alphabetizing the labels, but the order in the bibliography still isn't alphabetical. What can I do to continue using your style and get an alphabetical bibliography?

Comment: @jdc, how do you want the bibliography sorted?

Comment: I'd like articles 1. by Ga. and S., 2. by Ga. and Za., 3. by Go. and M., 2014, 4., by Go. and M., 2017, and 5 by Gr., W., and Zi. to sort in this order. Right now, my bibliography orders them as [GoM14], [GoM17], [GaS], [GrWZi], [GaZa] and I don't know how to change this.

Comment: do you still want the alphabetic labels? If they aren't sorted by label, how will people easily find what the citation refers to?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The thing at the beginning was just listing names in the order I wanted them, not the labels I wanted. The second list is the labels produced by the style, but with disambiguating second letters thrown in to emphasize the failure to alphabetize. I do want those labels, yes, but I also want them in the former order, not the latter.

Comment: Can you change you MWE to your actual data? GoM14], [GoM17], [GaS], [GrWZi], [GaZa] is obviously not sorted by label. But your example above is sorted by label.

Comment: jdc, what Joseph Wright meant (I think) is that the (plain) IEEE style is not sorted, which means the numeric labels will appear in the order of citation. If you choose `ieee-alphabetic` then each entry receives an alphanumeric label (generated from the entrykey and the last two digits of the year) and the bibliography is sorted in the alphabetical order of these labels, not of the authors names. So, the message is, if you want your bibliography sorted in alphabetical order of the names of the authors, you should choose another appropriate style, for example "authoryear".

Comment: @gusbrs, I changed the entrykeys and years iin the hopes this would change things, but it didn't.

Comment: @DavidPurton: I'll change the MWE as you suggest

Comment: I'm mistaken about the entrykeys (your attempt to manipulate the labels misguided me). The labels are generated from the authors names (depends on the case, but for two authors, the initials of the surnames) and the last two digits of the year. None of this is information you want to tamper with "to get the desired label". It is the actual bibliographic information of the entry.

Comment: @gusbrs: OK, the real information is up now.

Comment: That's a good starting point. From that, I can tell you that the bibliography is well sorted (by the citation label, which is generated from the authors surnames and year, and so on). So there is nothing to fix, actually. The question then boils down to: do you want to have the IEEE style or do you want to have your bibliography sorted by the authors surnames? You can't have both.

Comment: Now add the output you want. As @gusbrs says, this is exactly the expected output from the settings you are supplying to `biblatex`.

Comment: Oh god. I couldn't see what you were saying for the longest time. Now I see it. I really want the surnames alphabetized, not the labels, but something with similar formatting to `ieee-alphabetic`, if not that style itself. So what can I do?

Comment: @jdc, you can pass `sorting=nty` to `biblatex`. The bibliography will then be sorted by author. But your labels will be hard to find because they won't be in alphabetical order. Do you want to then create a different kind of label that will match the order of your bibliography?

Comment: Godsend! Thank you! I was losing what's left of my mind. I don't have enough labels that it's an issue, I think, but it's an interesting problem. What kind of label would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a perfect answer because the alphabetical order of labels is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of your bibliography. But it might be close enough.

I suggest using `sorting=nyt` so references sort by year before title. Then Use a label template like this:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[varwidth]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}
```

**Full MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{galazgarciasearle2011,
  title={Cohomogeneity one {Alexandrov} spaces},
  author={Fernando Galaz-Garc{\'i}a and Catherine Searle},
  journal={Transform. Groups},
  volume={16},
  number={1},
  pages={91--107},
  year={2011}
}
@electronic{galazgarciazarei2015,
  title={Cohomogeneity one topological manifolds revisited},
  author={Galaz-Garc{\'i}a, Fernando and Zarei, Masoumeh},
  year={2015},
  howpublished = "\url{http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.09068}",
  eprint = {1503.09068},
  archivePrefix = {arXiv}
}
@article{goertschesmare2014,
  author = "Oliver Goertsches and Mare, Augustin-Liviu",
  journal = "Topology Appl.",
  pages = "36--52",
  publisher = "Elsevier",
  title = "{Equivariant cohomology of cohomogeneity one actions}",
  volume = "167",
  year = "2014"
}
@article{goertschesmare2017,
  title={Equivariant cohomology of cohomogeneity-one actions: The topological case},
  author={Goertsches, Oliver and Mare, Augustin-Liviu},
  journal={Topology Appl.},
  year={2017}
}
@article{grovewilkingziller2008,
  title={Positively curved cohomogeneity one manifolds and 3-{Sasakian} geometry},
  author={K. Grove and B. Wilking and W. Ziller},
  journal={J.~Differential Geom.},
  volume={78},
  pages={33--111},
  year={2008}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=ieee-alphabetic,sorting=nyt]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[varwidth]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}
\begin{document}    
\cite{galazgarciasearle2011}
\cite{galazgarciazarei2015}
\cite{goertschesmare2014}
\cite{goertschesmare2017}
\cite{grovewilkingziller2008}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if we used `\field[strwidth=20,strside=right]{labelname}`...   ;-)  +1 btw, I think this is indeed the best compromise for the conflicting requirements.

Comment: right, having the short labels and forcing `nty` or `nyt` onto the ref section would just be offensive towards the creators of biblatex and the ieee style, imho. this is a good compromise.